# Create thumbnail after upload, PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, thumbnails

I have implemented a file upload for pictures on my page, and tried to somehow generate thumbnails with the intention of clicking them to view via fancybox. The upload works but my function to create a thumbnail doesn't.
(This is included in my upload.php, right after "move_uploaded_file":

```
<?php
$src = $subdir.$fileupload['name'];

function make_thumb($src) 
{

$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);    //For testing purposes only jpeg now
$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);
$desired_width = 220;

$desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($virtual_image, realpath('./Thumbnails/filename.jpg'));    //Temporary filename, will be changed
}
?>
```

Just FYI, this is an assignment and since I am a php beginner, I did use google, but can't find the problem in my case. Maybe my understanding of php is lacking too much.

Comment: Please enable error reporting so you can start learning from the problems PHP is trying to tell you about.

Comment: What goes wrong? Is there an error or does it just not function as expected?

Comment: 1.) Will do, need to check how I can enable error reporting first. 2.) No error, nothing happens at all, which I find strange since my experience with php has been coupled with lots of error messages

Comment: So, after enabling error reporting (error_reporting(E_ALL);), nothing has popped up. So i'm guessing something is working, just not as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `img_resize` function, it is good for the most popular image formats

```
   function img_resize($src, $dest, $width, $height, $rgb = 0xFFFFFF, $quality = 100)
   {
        if (!file_exists($src))
            return false;

        $size = getimagesize($src);

        if ($size === false)
            return false;

        $format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/') + 1));
        $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
        if (!function_exists($icfunc))
            return false;

        $x_ratio = $width / $size[0];
        $y_ratio = $height / $size[1];

        $ratio = min($x_ratio, $y_ratio);
        $use_x_ratio = ($x_ratio == $ratio);

        $new_width = $use_x_ratio ? $width : floor($size[0] * $ratio);
        $new_height = !$use_x_ratio ? $height : floor($size[1] * $ratio);
        $new_left = $use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($width - $new_width) / 2);
        $new_top = !$use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($height - $new_height) / 2);

        $isrc = $icfunc($src);
        $idest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        imagefill($idest, 0, 0, $rgb);

        if (($format == 'gif') or ($format == 'png')) {
            imagealphablending($idest, false);
            imagesavealpha($idest, true);
        }

        if ($format == 'gif') {
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($idest, 255, 255, 255, 127);
            imagefilledrectangle($idest, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
            imagecolortransparent($idest, $transparent);
        }

        imagecopyresampled($idest, $isrc, $new_left, $new_top, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $size[0], $size[1]);

        getResultImage($idest, $dest, $size['mime']);

        imagedestroy($isrc);
        imagedestroy($idest);

        return true;
    }

    function getResultImage($dst_r, $dest_path, $type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'image/jpg':
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                return imagejpeg($dst_r, $dest_path, 90);
                break;
            case 'image/png';
                return imagepng($dst_r, $dest_path, 2);
                break;
            case 'image/gif';
                return imagegif($dst_r, $dest_path);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @JuanMendes It is not a problem, it is desicion :)

Comment: the whole mime/function_exists stuff is pointless and could simply be `imagecreatefromstring(readfile($src))`

Comment: @MarcB `imagecreatefromstring` has troubles with image transparency areas